# SQL Query Taking Nearly 3 Minutes?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm hoping someone could shed some light on why this query is taking nearly 3 minutes to execute with the result being just 18 rows.

The problem occurs when adding to the `WHERE` clause to show results up to 2 months ago.

The following query takes around 2 minutes 40 seconds to execute:

```
SELECT carts.id AS id, carts.order_id, carts.product_id, users.title, users.first_name, users.last_name, details.date_time, details.status 
    FROM orders_carts AS carts 
        LEFT JOIN orders_details AS details 
        ON carts.order_id = details.order_id

        LEFT JOIN orders_users AS users 
        ON users.order_id = details.order_id 

        WHERE carts.product_id = '11698'
        AND details.date_time >= now()-INTERVAL 2 month
        ORDER BY id DESC;
```

This query however executes in about 1.5 seconds:

```
SELECT carts.id AS id, carts.order_id, carts.product_id, users.title, users.first_name, users.last_name, details.date_time, details.status 
    FROM orders_carts AS carts 
        LEFT JOIN orders_details AS details 
        ON carts.order_id = details.order_id

        LEFT JOIN orders_users AS users 
        ON users.order_id = details.order_id 

        WHERE carts.product_id = '11698'
        ORDER BY id DESC
```

The only thing added was `AND details.date_time >= now()-INTERVAL 2 month`, I have no idea why it's causing the lag though. Can anyone help?

Comment: before you add the new line how long did it take?

Comment: YOu need index for the `date_time` as well if its not there already.

Comment: Is there an index on the `date_time` field on the `orders-details` table? If that table is huge then it would do a full table scan instead of an index seek. Also changing the order of the where clauses (time first) may have an effect.

Comment: Questions about query performance generally require CREATE statements for the relevant tables AND the EXPLAIN. This is no exception!

Comment: Thanks so much guys, the date_time field wasn't indexed.